# How can i have a pagination on my wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to have a pagination on my custom [Products](https://dama.ci/produits/)  page that is not the default one in Woocommerce.

I used Elementor to customize this page and after some research I saw that I could call a function that is already integrated in WordPress using the < paginate_links > function.

The only problem is that I have no idea where to call this function in order to have a pagination on my product page.

To be more precise, i would like to know where exactly i have to change or add my php functions, and what code should i use to get my pagination.

Answer (score 1):

Normally it is in the archive.php or a version of that file name specific to your post-type. But before you go and change it, create a child theme in case you haven't done that already. In the child theme folder, you then duplicate the archive.php or similar to make it overwrite the one from the parent theme. This way you keep your version of the theme clean and updatable without losing any changes.

(For creating a child-theme you will need to create at least a style.css [with a WordPress-specific comment, you can google] and a functions.php-file that needs a bit of php-code to enqueue the child-themes scripts and styles. The code for the functions.php can also be found by a quick google search. You then just place the style.css and the functions.php into a new folder you name in the pattern [foldername of your themes name]-child. You then place this folder next to the parent-themes folder in the "/wp-content/themes/"-directory.)

And here you go for the pagination: https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination

Comment: Since i already have a child theme created, i will try to do that right now, so basically i just need to add the pagination code on my archive.php ?

Comment: It depends... Wordpress uses the most precise template it can find. In case your post-type was named redberries it would use redberries-archive.php over archive.php if it exists.

Comment: In your case it will most likely be product-archive.php, if i read the wordpress-class correctly. Once you found it, you copy that file into the child-theme-folder and then it will overwrite whatever the parent-themes archive-template did.

Comment: I'm struggling to find my template page file but i will keep trying editing some templates till i find the correct file